# Installing Laravel 4 using composer.phar without terminal access

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I don't have a shell or command line terminal to install composer.phar, what can I do? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation with my hosting company. Even though I had an SSH access, the PHP installed in the SSH environment was 5.2.17 and I couldn't install composer. The web server itself had PHP 5.4 and I have managed to find a workaround and got Composer and Laravel 4 installed by running a PHP file on the web server.

For Laravel 4 to work, you need at least PHP 5.3 along with some required extensions, i.e. MCRYPT. You can check your PHP version and other related information via the `phpinfo()` function.

The PHP file I used to get Laravel installed is below. Copy `composer.phar` to your Laravel installation path.

```
<?php

putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . '/path/to/laravel');

$command = '/usr/local/php54/bin/php-cli /path/to/laravel/composer.phar install -d /path/to/laravel';
$output =  system($command . ' 2>&1');
echo('<pre>' . $command . "\n" . $output);

?>
```

I had to use a full path for the php command line, because the default `php` was pointing to the old version, 5.2.17. Thus, you may not need the full path. If you do, adjust the path accordingly.

I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but now I have a new problem.. git is not installed! any way I found that a can have Lavel Installe/update  in my server and when I have to use my clients server I just copy the "vendor" dir!

Comment: Wow that's even worse. I would suggest you to switch to a better web server, preferably with shell access and a support team who would answer to your demands, i.e. for installing git if it's not already installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can just download [composer.phar](http://getcomposer.org/download/), put it in your application root (near the composer.json file) and then run :

```
php composer.phar install
```

On Windows there is also a composer.exe installer available.

Comment: I made a .php file in the same directory, With this script: exec('php composer.phar install', $output, $return_var);echo $return_var  it return 0. Is that what you mean?

Comment: We should start at the beginning : why don't you have access to a command line terminal ? What's your OS ?

Comment: Normaly I use the hosting service my client has and not all of them have good support or information tu access.